# Error when installing awsebcli

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I tried to install AWS EB CLI on Windows 10, but got an error.
Python version: 3.5

What I did:

```
python -m pip install awsebcli
```

What I got:

```
......
copying lib3\yaml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\yaml
running build_ext
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
checking if libyaml is compilable
error: [WinError 2] ═ The system cannot find the file specified
----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Maksim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-dkbpajst\\pyyaml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Maksim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-y0knjbc5-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Maksim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-dkbpajst\pyyaml
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: what's your python version? (eb cli is not compatible with 3.5)

Comment: Python version: 3.5. What version of python need to eb cli ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html): *"The EB CLI is not compatible with Python 3.5."*.
I'm on python Python 3.4.3 and it works just fine. It also works nicely with python 2.7.x

Comment: for me it not  working on 2.7.x or 3.4.3 or 3.5.x have you any idea how to solve this issue